# Le(s) « mot-code » en épithète des informations qu'il(s) représente(nt) : apport cohérent ou préposition ?

Tags: anglais, prépositions, usage, terminologie, formulation

Dns la presse en langue anglaise j'ai vu des phrases où l'on trouve un terme de vocabulaire du domaine du renseignement comme « Top secret *codeword* information is no joke », « This is *code-word* information [...] » ou « [...] top-secret *code-word* intelligence [...] » (mes italiques). [*Termium*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=CODE%20WORD&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs) recense l'emploi normalisé de l'OTAN, entre autres, et donne en français « mot-code ». La *Base de données terminologiques officielle de l'OTAN* a deux fiches pour « code word », la première non spécifiquement associée à un domaine particulier alors que la deuxième porte la mention « Science & technologie - Télécommunications » ; les voici dans l'ordre :

> [1213]
>   [EN] A cryptonym used to identify sensitive intelligence data.
>  [FR] Mot
>   dont le sens caché sert à identifier des informations
>   classifiées.
>
> ---
>
> [7429]
>   [EN] A word which has been assigned a classification and a classified
>   meaning to safeguard intentions and information regarding a classified
>   plan or operation.
>  [FR] Mot auquel on a donné une classification et un
>   sens caché dans le but de protéger les informations relatives à un
>   projet ou une opération classifié.
>
> [ [*Base de données terminologiques officielle
>   de l'OTAN*](https://nso.nato.int/natoterm/content/nato/pages/home.html?lg=fr) à « code word / mot-code », deux entrées : 1213 et 7429 ]

Il va sans dire que l'information à laquelle on s'intéresse généralement est celle dont le sens n'est pas caché, et c'est pour cette raison qu'il le serait. Je peux écrire :

> Renseignements/informations mot-code classifié(e)s très secret/[très secret défense ([France](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/classifier/16416?q=classifi%C3%A9#16287))].

---

- La notion à l'effet que le *mot-code* représente les renseignements ou les informations est-elle suffisamment réalisée par un apport (en complémentation, en qualification ou ...) en fonction d'épithète ; est-ce ainsi que s'emploie le terme *mot-code* ou a-t-on besoin d'une préposition pour l'introduire ici ou carrément d'une autre formulation pour exprimer ce dont il s'agit de manière claire et précise ?

Comment: J'ai l'impression que ça ne marche pas parce que code-word est un nom utilisé comme un adjectif en anglais. En français on comprendrait que l'information se présente sous forme de mot-code (les autres constructions avec noms apposés semblent dans ce cas improbables). « Information ou renseignements à mot-code » serait la façon de le dire, mais ne l'ayant jamais entendu, je ne sais pas si on comprendrait.

Comment: Le cas de « secret défense » utilisé comme un adjectif est tout aussi intéressant…

Comment: Merci, bien en anglais ils ont le _buffalo_ qui peut même avoir pour fonction celle d'une relative. Je n'ai traité d'aucun contexte parce que je n'avais pas envie de parler de l'actu. mais vu qu'une personne ne s'exprime pas normalement en charade, je devais déduire que la construction pouvait valoir « ayant (déjà) été en » ou _sous la forme de_ comme vous dites ; mais si j'essaie de dire _ayant fait l'objet_, j'aurais besoin d'utiliser le mot-code avec le suffixe -age, et la question se dirige davantage vers la différence d'avec le chiffrement etc. Quand vous employez _à_, c'est ds. quel sens

Comment: Est-ce de penser à « très secret défense » dans le sens de _à la défense nationale_ pour _dans le domaine de_ ou qq. comme ça qui vous fait dire que ce serait avec _à_ ? Est-ce dans le sens de la vocation ou de la destination ? Mais comme pas tous les documents très secret défense sont en mot-code, alors comment _à_ peut-elle rendre la nuance possible entre le renseignement qui l'est, voire concurremment, et celui qui l'a déjà été ?? Je trouve avec _défense_ bien plus clair, une étiquette. Je pense que c'est ce genre de réflexion qui fait faire des bulles à un cerveau.. Merci. @StéphaneGimenez

Comment: Wikipedia: Code word (figure of speech), a term chosen for propaganda value//Code word", a rhetorical device used in political propaganda//
Code word, in cryptography and telecommunications. Pour le troisième sens, en français: mot d'un code secret. http://www.huyghe.fr/actu_246.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even as it’s used in English to modify “information,” either as a single one-word attributive adjective or as a single hyphenated one, I think “code[-]word” could use some help to capture more coherently the [sensitive] nature of that information.

I say this primarily because, in addition to the one you describe, I see another possible attributive use of “code[-]word” in “code[-]word information” as meaning simply/literally “information **about** code words,” such as a list of code words (with or without their corresponding projects/operations) currently or formerly in use by a/n [spy] agency
 (cf: the attributive use of “login” or “credit card” in “Never reveal your **login/credit card** information!”).

In English, to distinguish it better in my mind from the “login/credit card” attributive use just mentioned above, I read “code[-]word information” in the attributive use at issue to mean either “code[-]word[-]**protected** information” or “code[-]word **level** information,” with both of which standing for “information requiring code[-]word clearance to access” and with this in mind, I’d humbly propose that it would require more than adding a simple proposition in French to coherently transform the noun “mot-code” to an attributive adjective of “information.”

Although with nothing to support me, I do think, however, that “mot-code” alone could coherently modify words like “niveau” or “habilitation” (just as I’ve used “code[-]word” to modify “level” and “clearance” in English) and perhaps even a word like “genre” (which is actually my favorite):

Renseignements/informations [d’un/du] niveau mot-code classifié(e)s/classé(e)s très secret/[très secret défense].

Renseignements/informations [d’une] habilitation mot-code classifié(e)s/classé(e)s très secret/[très secret défense].

Renseignements/informations [du] genre mot-code classifié(e)s/classé(e)s très secret/[très secret défense].

Comment: Thank you! It is not so much imho that the word has the ability to modify niveau/habilitation but rather that by phrasing it like so the construction lends itself to using a compound for a preposition and a determiner i.e. du and this helps smooth it so to speak. Also _genre_ allows for this nuance about something which by virtue of its value might be destined to be, as opposed to being actually _in_ such a state imho. Your discussion captures some of the concerns I had over using the word with not cue as to what it's supposed to "change". Well done! Cheers.